# How to stop plotting a mean if the list of values is empty

Tags: netlogo

I have a plot which has the following in the plot window (i.e. not in my code):

```
plot mean [todays_pay] of workers with [ pcolor = lime ]
plot mean [todays_pay] of workers with [ pcolor = yellow ]
```

This works fine except when all the workers leave one of the colours.

Then, understandably, I get an error:

```
List is empty.
error while observer running MEAN
called by plot 'Average Pay' pen 'default' update code
```

Is there any way to avoid this in the plot window, or will I have to create the plot from code?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to skip plotting in this case, use a conditional:

```
let _w (workers with [pcolor = lime]) if (any? _w) [plot mean [todays_pay] of _w]
```

Comment: Note, though, using the `plot` primitive and sometimes skipping a tick runs the risk of the x axis of the plot getting out of sync with the number of ticks that have passed. You might want `ifelse any? _w [ plot ... ] [ plot 0 ]`

Comment: Or, if you'd rather skip a point than plot `0`: `if any? _w [ plotxy ticks mean [ todays_pay ] of _w ]`.